# Get dent out of downspout

Tags: gutters

A couple of my gutter downspouts have dents in them.

Is there anyway to get dent out of downspout?

Maybe take it to an auto body shop, LOL.

Comment: Yes use a hammer and an anvil for backing - just like they do at a body shop - or splurge $5 for new ones ..

Comment: Call Batman? (... Harvey Dent).  Or try a 1x2 with an old rag wrapped around it & taped and force the dents out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but depending on the material it may need o be done differently.

I'm gonna assume its copper / something that can be soldered, as aluminum ones are typically 0.019", very thin, usually you may even be able to get a dent out by hand. If not, a dolly and a hammer, or as commented above, get a new one for $10.

For copper and other materials that you can solder, you may try the same way, or solder a piece of metal to it, pull on that piece then remove the solder / soldered piece. You can try to do the same with aluminum and some sort of flue or suction cup.

Comment: I can probably count the number of homes I've seen in my life with copper downspouts on one hand. Are they common where you are?

Comment: @isherwood Very common in Massachusetts. I guess it depends on the part of the country, weather, economics.